# .etl files (Event Tracing for Windows (ETW)) created are exceeding MaximumFileSize

Tags: c#, windows, etl, etw

I'm using ETW with MaximumFileSize as 10MB. See below configurations

[image: ETW configuration details in registry]

But .etl files created has size more than 10MB.

[image: .etl fies created]

What could be the reason?